# Exception when I am calling local service using volley

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I want to use volley library to call a local webservice which is existed in my pc and I used the ip of my pc to call the service , but I am receiving this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:136)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.<init>(JsonRequest.java:58)
            at com.imona.android.volley.AuthenticatedJsonRequest.<init>(AuthenticatedJsonRequest.java:26)
            at com.imona.android.webservices.TasksService.getAllTasks(TasksService.java:36)
            at com.imona.android.fragments.TaskListFragment.onCreateView(TaskListFragment.java:46)
```

How can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just updating volley from this link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+archive/master.tar.gz
solved my problem